# Is there a way to check if part of the URL contains a certain string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Is there a way to check if part of the URL contains a certain string:

Eg. `<% if current_spree_page?("/products/*") %>`, where `*` could be anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tested, and gmacdougall's answer works, I had already found a solution though.

This is what I used to render different layouts depending on what the url is:

```
  url = request.path_info
  if url.include?('products')
    render :layout => 'product_layout'
  else
    render :layout => 'layout'
  end
```

The important thing to note is that different pages will call different methods within the controller (eg. show, index). What I did was put this code in its own method and then I am calling that method where needed.

Comment: I don't think if the `include?` does the work right.

What if the keyword "products" is elsewhere in the path?

For example, if the agenda with the name "user_projects" exists, then it will match this value too.

Answer (score 8):

If you are at a place where you have access to the [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) you can do the following:

```
request.path.start_with?('/products')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `include?` method

`my_string = "abcdefg"
if my_string.include? "cde"
   puts "String includes 'cde'"`
end`

Remember that `include?` is case sensetive. So if my_string in the example above would be something like "abcDefg" (with an uppercase D), `include?("cde")` would return `false`. You may want to do a `downcase()` before calling `include?()`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give absolutely the cleanest ways of checking your URL. I want to share a way of doing this using a regular expression so you can **check your URL for a string at a particular location in the URL**.

This method is useful when you have locales as first part of your URL like /en/users.

```
module MenuHelper
  def is_in_begin_path(*url_parts)
    url_parts.each do |url_part|
      return true if request.path.match(/^\/\w{2}\/#{url_part}/).present?
    end
    false
  end
end
```

This helper method picks out the part after the second slash if the first part contains 2 word characters as is the case if you use locales. Drop this in your ApplicationController to have it available anywhere.

Example:

```
is_in_begin_path('users', 'profile')
```

That matches /en/**users**/4, /en/**profile**, /nl/**users**/9/statistics, /nl/**profile** etc.